# One line command with variable, word count and zcat

Tags: bash, csv, unix, awk, command-line

I have many files on a server which contains many lines:

```
201701010530.contentState.csv.gz
201701020530.contentState.csv.gz
201701030530.contentState.csv.gz
201701040530.contentState.csv.gz
```

I would like with one line command this result:

```
170033|20170101
169865|20170102
170010|20170103
170715|20170104
```

The goal is to have the number of lines of each file, just by keeping the date which is already in the filename of the file.

I tried this but the result is not in one line but two...

```
for f in $(ls -1 2017*gz);do zcat $f | wc -l;echo $f | awk '{print substr($0,1,8)}';done
```

Thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `zcat file | wc -l` to get the number of lines.

For the name, I understand it is enough to extract the first 8 characters:

```
$ t="201701030530.contentState.csv.gz"
$ echo "${t:0:8}"
20170103
```

All together:

```
for file in 2017*gz;
do
    lines=$(zcat "$file" | wc -l)
    printf "%s|%s\n" "$lines" "${file:0:8}"
done > myresult.csv
```

Note the usage of `for file in 2017*gz;` to go through the files matching the `2017*gz` pattern: this suffices, no need to parse `ls`!

Answer (score 1):

Use `zgrep -c ^ file` to count the lines, here encapsulated in awk:

```
$ awk 'FNR==1{ "zgrep -c ^ " FILENAME | getline s; print s "|" substr(FILENAME,1,8) }' *.gz
12|20170101
```

The whole `"zgrep -c ^ " FILENAME` should probably be in a var (`s`) and then `s | getline s`.